# How to print \ in java

Tags: java, printing, escaping, character, println

I want to use the code
    System.out.println("\");
But whenever I do this the \ turns blue and gives me the error "illegal escape character in string literal".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [escape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) it:

```
System.out.println("\\");
```